# Avoid click on two button rapidly android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two `buttons` in my `layout`. Now both buttons perform a different network operation using `coroutines`. Problem is user rapidly clicks on both the buttons and at a certain point, things get messy. How can I put some throttle in the click of both the buttons? The below method works only for one `view` at a time.

```
fun View.setClickListener(debounceTime: Long = CLICK_DEBOUNCE_DURATION, action: () -> Unit) {
  this.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    private var lastClickTime: Long = 0

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
      if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < debounceTime) return
      else action()

      lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: One way is to not put execution logic into your buttons, but instead make them call some method in your activity/fragment/whatever (like `buttonPressed(buttonId)` or smth more specific) and track the cooldown there.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `lastClickTime` variable global in global scope. And define same on click code on both button with your desire action.

```
// Make this variable global, Outside of any methods. 
private var lastClickTime: Long = 0


fun View.setClickListener(debounceTime: Long = CLICK_DEBOUNCE_DURATION, action: () -> Unit) {
  this.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
      if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < debounceTime) return
      else action()

      lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    }
  })
}
```